# How can we use both sql and oracle database connection using one object only

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ado.net

I wants to fetch the data from database using C++.Net. I need to do this irrespective of db used in the system. But i don't want to change my code for each database. I am looking for a solution in C++.Net, please do help..
This is what i have now;

Oracle:

`OracleConnection *myOracleConnection;
 OracleDataAdapter * myDataAdapter;
 DataSet * myDataSet;
 myOracleConnection = new OracleConnection(S"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.175)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SCDB)));User Id=user;Password=pw;");
 myOracleConnection->Open();
 myDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(S"select dbms_xmlgen.getxml(' select * from SampleTable') from dual ",myOracleConnection);
 myDataSet = new DataSet("Sample");`

Sql:

```
`SqlConnection      *mySQLConnection;
SqlDataAdapter * myDataAdapter;
DataSet * myDataSet;
mySQLConnection = new SqlConnection(S"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDb;User Id=user;Password=pw;");
    mySQLConnection->Open();
    myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(S"select * from [SampleTable]",mySQLConnection);
    myDataSet = new DataSet("Sample");`
```

i wants to do both connection using one connection object. Is there any idea to achieve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you c++ code, but I can help you how to do it. It will be difficult to do it in one connection, but your can get a DataSet back which will work, and you only have to do the code once.

Create a method will return a DataSet, and pass the query as well as what type of connection should be used, in this method depending on tour connection type you do your query and return your result.

You can also add a connectionstring if you wish.

Something like this (it is c# though)

```
    DataSet GetDataSet(string sqlQuery, ConnectionType connType)
    {
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet("aDataSet");
        using (DataTable table = dataset.Tables.Add("aDataTable"))
        {
            switch (connType)
            {
                case ConnectionType.MSSQL:
                    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDb;User Id=user;Password=pw"))
                    {
                        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                table.Load(reader);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case ConnectionType.Oracle:
                    using (var conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.175)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=SCDB)));User Id=user;Password=pw"))
                    {
                        using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                table.Load(reader);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    enum ConnectionType { MSSQL, Oracle }
```

Comment: Thank u very much. i already tried this, i was looking for any other simpler method. :)

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you want in your question. There might be another way by using DbConnection and DbCommand, as both SqlConnetion and OracleConnection inherits from it

Comment: I am looking for the usage of DbConnection and DbCommand. I tried with DbConnection like this, DbConnection *conn; conn = new SqlConnection(S"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myDb;User Id=user;Password=pw;"); conn->Open(); myDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(S"select * from [LabOpsStatus]",conn); but i got an error "System::Data::SqlClient::SqlDataAdapter::SqlDataAdapter(System::String __gc *,System::String __gc *)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'System::Data::Common::DbConnection __gc *' to 'System::String __gc *'" –